# speeding up JSON parsing in Perl

Tags: json, performance, perl

I've been using the JSON package in a perl script that parses a long list of relatively short JSON strings and I profiled the process with Devel::NYTProf. It seems like most of the time is taken by the JSON `string` function in the parsing process.

Are there any speed-ups that I could use other than not using the JSON package and try to speed it up by parsing it myself?

EDIT: The JSON package was installed in the system using `cpanm`. If there are any speed-ups to be gained by optimizing the installation process, they are also welcomed.

Comment: Is `JSON::XS` installed on your system?

Comment: `if json::xs is not available, JSON uses a JSON::PP object instead of JSON::XS and it is very slow as pure-Perl.` from cpan docs for JSON module

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to install [JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON%3a%3aXS). Then, "use JSON" automatically uses the XS version. This module was written in C, and it has a very good performance.

Comment: Thanks, this made a huge difference. It's still about x2 slower than a regex, but more powerful to query using JSON.

Comment: The reason it's slower than your regular expression is probably that your regular expression would not be able to transform any kind of valid JSON to a Perl data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting workaround:

If you need to parse JSON so you can extrat smaller chunks from a large JSON object, and said JSON object comes via a webapp - simply parse and pare down the JSON to smaller chunk in the JavaScript before sending it to Perl.

JS has amazingly fast and efficient string-to-JSON parsers ([Douglas Crockford's parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), *not* `eval`, just to be clear), even if you start out with a string and *not* JSON datastructure itself.